# Hartshorne Example 5.2.2

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Let $X = \operatorname{Spec} A$, $Y \subseteq X$ closed subscheme defined by ideal $I \unlhd A$, and let $i : Y \rightarrow X$ denote the inclusion morphism.

Then, Hartshorne claims that $i_{*}\mathcal{O}_{Y} \cong (A/I)^{\sim}$, the sheaf associated to the  $A$-module $A/I$.

I am having trouble proving this rigorously.

Firstly, as $Y$ is a closed subscheme, it follows $i^{\sharp} : \mathcal{O}_{X} \rightarrow i_{*}\mathcal{O}_{Y}$ is surjective. Therefore, we have

$i_{*}\mathcal{O}_{Y} \cong \mathcal{O}_{X} /\mathcal{I} $

where $\mathcal{I} :=$ ker $i^{\sharp}$.

Hence, I think a good idea is to prove that
$\mathcal{O}_{X} /\mathcal{I} \cong (A/I)^{\sim}$.

But I have not been able to come up with any argument that I find convincing. For example, I looked at the surjective map

$\mathcal{O}_{X} \rightarrow (A/I)^{\sim} $

and tried to prove its kernel is $\mathcal{I}$, but I couldn't come up with a rigorous answer.

Maybe my problem is that I don't really understand what the map $(i,i^{\sharp})$ is?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Is the correspondence between modules and quasicoherent sheaves alerady proved at this point in the book?

Comment: You need to unravel some definitions. Start with $Y$. What is it? What's its structure sheaf? Do $i_*\mathcal{O}_Y$ next: what is it?

Comment: @KReiser If my understanding is correct, then $(Y,\mathcal{O}_{Y}) \cong (Spec A/I, \mathcal{O}_{SpecA/I})$ and $\mathcal{O}_{SpecA/I}$ is the usual sheaf on an affine scheme given in terms of sections into localisations of the ring which locally look like fractions. This is also the sheaf associated to the $A$-module $A/I$. Then, $i_{*}\mathcal{O}_{Y}$ is the `same' as $\mathcal{O}_{Y}$, because I think $i_{*}\mathcal{O}_{Y}(U) = \mathcal{O}_{Y}(Y \cap U) $?

Comment: @KReiser I think you can show that they agree up to isomorphism on principle open sets. But is it true that $\mathcal{O}_{Y}(Y \cap D(f)) \cong \mathcal{O}_{SpecA/I}(D([f]))$?

Comment: Yes, all of that's correct (taking $[f]$ to mean $f+ I \in A/I$). Again, all you need to do is unravel definitions: a prime ideal $p\subset A$ is in $D(f)$ if $f\notin p$, all the prime ideals of $A/I$ are of the form $p/I$ for $p\subset A$ prime containing $I$, and then for a prime ideal $p\subset A$ containing $I$, we have $f\in p$ iff $[f]\in p/I$. Why don't you try writing all of this up in to an answer to your own question?

Answer (score 1):

Following the discussion in the comment section, I will try to answer my own question. My exposition may not be fully rigorous, but I think it contains the right ideas following hints given in the comments.

We have

$(Y,\mathcal{O}_{Y}) =$ $(Spec A/I, \mathcal{O}_{Spec A/I }$).

Recall,

$\mathcal{O}_{Y}(U) = \{s : U \rightarrow \coprod_{p \in U} (A/I)_{p} : \cdots  \}$ (such that "locally looks like fractions").

Also, note that

$i_{*}\mathcal{O}_{Y}(U) = \mathcal{O}_{Y}(U \cap Y) = \{s : U' \rightarrow \coprod_{p \in U'} (A/I)_{p} : \cdots  \}$

where $U' := U \cap Y \subseteq Y$ is open in $Y$.

Then, note that for principle open $D(f) \subseteq X$,

$i_{*}\mathcal{O}_{Y}(D(f)) = \mathcal{O}_{Y}(D(f)\cap Y) = \mathcal{O}_{Spec A/I}(D([f]))$.

But,

$\mathcal{O}_{Spec A/I}(D([f])) \cong (A/I)^{\sim}(D(f))$

via

$(A/I)^{\sim}(D(f)) \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{Spec A/I}(D([f])) $

$s \mapsto s'$

where if $\pi : A \rightarrow A/I$ denotes the projection map, then

$s'(\pi(p)) := s(p)$.

Thus, this isomorphism on the principle open sets yields an isomorphism of the sheaves.